# c# "x" does not contain definition for "y"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having some problems stemming from my beginner level understanding of C# and OOP. But I have been unable to understand what I am doing wrong by searching for answers.

My Model - KeyVisualBlock.cs:

```
[Display(Order = 90,
GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content)]
[AllowedTypes(typeof(FormContainerBlock))]
public virtual ContentReference ContactForm { get; set; }
```

My Controller - KeyVisualBlockController.cs:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Example.Site.Models.Blocks;
using Example.Site.Models.Pages;
using Example.Site.Models.ViewModels;

using EPiServer;
using EPiServer.ServiceLocation;
using EPiServer.Web;
using EPiServer.Web.Mvc;

namespace Example.Site.Controllers
{
    public class KeyVisualBlockController : BlockController<KeyVisualBlock>
    {
        public override ActionResult Index(KeyVisualBlock currentBlock)
        {
            var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
            var startPage = contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(SiteDefinition.Current.StartPage);

            KeyVisualBlockViewModel model = new KeyVisualBlockViewModel
            {
                SearchLink = startPage.SearchPageLink,
                CurrentKeyVisualBlock = currentBlock
            };

            return PartialView("KeyVisualBlock", model);
        }

    }

    public class KeyContactBlockController : BlockController<ContactBlock>
    {
        public override ActionResult Index(ContactBlock currentBlock)
        {
            ContactBlockViewModel model = new ContactBlockViewModel(currentBlock);

            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Blocks/ContactBlock.cshtml", model);
        }
    }
}
```

My View Model:

```
using Example.Site.Models.Blocks;

using EPiServer;
using EPiServer.Core;
using EPiServer.Forms.Implementation.Elements;
using EPiServer.ServiceLocation;
using System;

namespace Example.Site.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class KeyVisualBlockViewModel
    {
        public PageReference SearchLink { get; set; }
        public KeyVisualBlock CurrentKeyVisualBlock { get; set; }
    }

    public class KeyContactBlockViewModel
    {
        public KeyContactBlockViewModel(ContactBlock KeycurrentBlock)
        {
            IContentLoader contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();

            this.KeyCurrentBlock = KeycurrentBlock;

            if (!ContentReference.IsNullOrEmpty(this.KeyCurrentBlock.ContactForm))
            {
                this.ContactFormID = contentLoader.Get<FormContainerBlock>(this.KeyCurrentBlock.ContactForm)?.Form?.FormGuid;
            }
        }

        public ContactBlock KeyCurrentBlock { get; set; }
        public Guid? ContactFormID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And lastly my View:

```
<header>
    <h2 id="@(string.Format("formWrapperHeader_{0}", Model.ContactFormID))"
        data-header-success-message="@Model.KeyCurrentBlock.SuccessHeadline">
        @Html.PropertyFor(x => x.KeyCurrentBlock.Headline)
    </h2>
</header>
```

The error I get in my View is the following:

> 'KeyVisualBlockViewModel' does not contain a definition for
>   'KeyCurrentBlock' and no accessible extension method 'KeyCurrentBlock'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'KeyVisualBlockViewModel' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What I am trying to do is add the ability to include a form into our KeyVisualBlock so that our editors can include forms into our page header sections.

Comment: The error message is right, there is no member named `KeyCurrentBlock` in the type `KeyVisualBlockViewModel`. Did you intend to use `CurrentKeyVisualBlock`?

Comment: The KeyCurrentBlock is a property on KeyVisualBlockViewModel, not on KeyContactBlockViewModel

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.